# В чем такое отличие x86 и x64 в VC++ 2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, x86-64

Навеяно [другим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1360182/195342), пытаясь ответить на который, обнаружил такое непонятное мне поведение VC++ 2019.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class String
{
public:
    String(char* str):p(str){};
    const char& operator[](size_t i) const { return p[i]; }
    char& operator[](size_t i)             { return p[i]; }
    operator const char* () const          { return p; }
    operator char* ()                      { return p; }
private:
    char* p;
};

int main() {
    char s[] = "123456";
    String name = s;
    std::cout << name[0] << std::endl;
    name[1] = '5';
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

На всякие возможные проблемы с памятью и иже с ними не смотрите, это просто урезанный до минимума код.

Так вот, при компиляции x64 строкой `cl /EHsc main.cpp` все проходит на ура.

А вот той же командой для x86 получаем

```
main.cpp  
main.cpp(20): error C2666: String::operator []: для перегрузок (4) есть подобные преобразования  
main.cpp(10): note: может быть "char &String::operator [](size_t)"  
main.cpp(9): note: или       "const char &String::operator [](size_t) const"  
main.cpp(20): note: или       "встроенный оператор C++[(const char *, int)"  
main.cpp(20): note: или       "встроенный оператор C++[(char *, int)"  
main.cpp(20): note: при попытке сопоставить список аргументов "(String, int)"  
main.cpp(21): error C2666: String::operator []: для перегрузок (4) есть подобные преобразования
main.cpp(10): note: может быть "char &String::operator [](size_t)"
main.cpp(9): note: или       "const char &String::operator [](size_t) const"
main.cpp(21): note: или       "встроенный оператор C++[(const char *, int)"
main.cpp(21): note: или       "встроенный оператор C++[(char *, int)"
main.cpp(21): note: при попытке сопоставить список аргументов "(String, int)"
```

Кто-то может пояснить, почему такое отличие при компиляции под разные платформы?...

P.S. G++: https://ideone.com/TbDfC2

Comment: Clang примерно тоже-самое говорит, только немного подробно: `error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'String' and 'int')`, и если явно сказать что мы имеем ввиду `size_t` то он все ест. Что один что другой. Там же просто размеры типов одинаковы. Вот он и не знает что взять. e.g: `...[(size_t)0]`...`...[(size_t)1]`

Comment: @Kotomi Да как обойти — понятно... но почему такая разница? Где-то MS не доработали? Или переработали? :) Или есть какая-то хитрость, специально допущенная?...

Comment: Ну это же то самое неявное привидение типов... Я с `-m32` не могу кстати собрать с GCC. он не может найти мне все что нужно для `<bits/c++config.h>`, так что не факт что он это съест.

Comment: @Kotomi установите пакет `g++-multilib`

Comment: Век живи — век учись...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

g++ ведёт себя аналогично: `g++ -m32 -c some.c++ -pedantic`

````
some.c++: In function ‘int main()’:
some.c++:20:22: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘String’ and ‘int’)
     std::cout << name[0] << std::endl;
                      ^
some.c++:20:22: note: candidate: operator[](const char*, int) <built-in>
some.c++:20:22: note: candidate: operator[](char*, int) <built-in>
some.c++:9:17: note: candidate: const char& String::operator[](size_t) const
     const char& operator[](size_t i) const { return p[i]; }
                 ^~~~~~~~
some.c++:10:11: note: candidate: char& String::operator[](size_t)
     char& operator[](size_t i)             { return p[i]; }
           ^~~~~~~~
some.c++:21:9: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘String’ and ‘int’)
     name[1] = '5';
         ^
some.c++:21:9: note: candidate: operator[](const char*, int) <built-in>
some.c++:21:9: note: candidate: operator[](char*, int) <built-in>
some.c++:9:17: note: candidate: const char& String::operator[](size_t) const
     const char& operator[](size_t i) const { return p[i]; }
                 ^~~~~~~~
some.c++:10:11: note: candidate: char& String::operator[](size_t)
     char& operator[](size_t i)             { return p[i]; }
           ^~~~~~~~```
````

32-х битный компилятор находит четыре варианта:

1. Оставить тип `String`, преобразовать `int` в `size_t`: `char& String::operator[](size_t)`
2. Оставить тип `String`, преобразовать `int` в `size_t`: `const char& String::operator[](size_t) const`
3. Преобразовать тип `String` в `char*`, оставить тип `int`: `[char *, int]`
4. Преобразовать тип `String` в `const char*`, оставить тип `int`: `[const char *, int]`

Во всех четырех вариантах один тип преобразуется, второй нет. Поэтому компилятор не может выбрать лучший кандидат.

В 64-х битном случае ситуация иная: встроенный оператор `[]` имеет сигнатуру `operator[](char*, long int)`

Так как литерал `0` имеет тип `int`, то опции 3 и 4 из списка выше превращаются в

3. Преобразовать тип `String` в `char*`, **преобразовать тип `int` в `long int`**: `[char *, long int]`
4. Преобразовать тип `String` в `const char*`, **преобразовать тип `int` в `long int`**: `[const char *, long int]`

Так как добавляется Promotion, который ухудшает кандидата, то компилятор отбрасывает эти кандидаты. Поэтому в 64-х битном случае компилируется без ошибок.

Чтобы запретить компилятору рассматривать встроенные операторы индексирования, явным образом сделайте литералы беззнаковыми: `0u` и `5u`. Тогда будет компилироваться и 64, и 32 бита.

PS. Тип встроенного оператора `[]`

ISO C++ 2020, глава 12.7

> 16 For every cv-qualified or cv-unqualified object type T there exist
> candidate operator functions of the form ... `T & operator[](T *, std::ptrdiff_t);`

То, что 64 битный g++ для `ptrdiff_t` использует `long int`, я установил экспериментально.

Comment: О, теперь вот что сказал G++: `ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second`

Comment: @Kotomi Добавьте `-pedantic`, чтобы превратить предупреждения в ошибки.

Comment: Ну да, это понятно, просто так он упамянул стандарт :)

Comment: @Kotomi версию стандарта не назвал ))

Comment: @PakUula `-pedantic` не превращает предупреждения в ошибки, это делает `-Werror`

Comment: @Harry добавил PS